# Extracting json array in Snowflake without knowing the key value

Tags: sql, json, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I don't know anything about json so apologies if my terminology is incorrect.
I am trying to extract a list of UUIDs from the following json object `PAYLOAD`:

```
{
    "AccountId": {
        "providerId": "12345",
        "provider": "ABCD"
    },
    "destinationAccountId": null,
    "referenceId": "ABCD1234",
    "repaymentAmounts": {
        "75e7dae4-3000-4b51-a1e2-555218d6c180": {
            "amount": 5.20,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "b7b7f744-db7f-48c9-8417-985d6fe137bc": {
            "amount": 0.24,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "49c69500-e9c0-433e-bd2e-cb387d1b688f": {
            "amount": 7.30,
            "currency": "GBP"
        }
    }
}
```

All I need is a table containing the UUIDs as follows:

| UUID |
| --- |
| 75e7dae4-3000-4b51-a1e2-555218d6c180 |
| b7b7f744-db7f-48c9-8417-985d6fe137bc |
| 49c69500-e9c0-433e-bd2e-cb387d1b688f |

Currently I have got as far as

```
JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT(PAYLOAD), 'repaymentAmounts')
```

The output of this is just the array in json format, not extracted:

```
{
        "75e7dae4-3000-4b51-a1e2-555218d6c180": {
            "amount": 5.20,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "b7b7f744-db7f-48c9-8417-985d6fe137bc": {
            "amount": 0.24,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "49c69500-e9c0-433e-bd2e-cb387d1b688f": {
            "amount": 7.30,
            "currency": "GBP"
        }
    }
```

I don't know how to extract the UUIDs as they do not have a key that I can reference. I'm not familiar enough with flatten to be able to use it for this although I suspect that will be part of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a recursive flatten and then exclude the keys `amount` and `currency` since those aren't what you want.  This works for the scenario you've requested, but might need tweaking if you have other keys in your actual data:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{
    "AccountId": {
        "providerId": "12345",
        "provider": "ABCD"
    },
    "destinationAccountId": null,
    "referenceId": "ABCD1234",
    "repaymentAmounts": {
        "75e7dae4-3000-4b51-a1e2-555218d6c180": {
            "amount": 5.20,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "b7b7f744-db7f-48c9-8417-985d6fe137bc": {
            "amount": 0.24,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "49c69500-e9c0-433e-bd2e-cb387d1b688f": {
            "amount": 7.30,
            "currency": "GBP"
        }
    }
}') as var)
SELECT y.key
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>x.var:repaymentAmounts, recursive=>True) y
WHERE y.key not in ('amount','currency');
```

You can also skip the recursive query and the filter, now that I look at it closer:

```
WITH x AS (
    SELECT parse_json('{
    "AccountId": {
        "providerId": "12345",
        "provider": "ABCD"
    },
    "destinationAccountId": null,
    "referenceId": "ABCD1234",
    "repaymentAmounts": {
        "75e7dae4-3000-4b51-a1e2-555218d6c180": {
            "amount": 5.20,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "b7b7f744-db7f-48c9-8417-985d6fe137bc": {
            "amount": 0.24,
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "49c69500-e9c0-433e-bd2e-cb387d1b688f": {
            "amount": 7.30,
            "currency": "GBP"
        }
    }
}') as var)
SELECT y.key
FROM x,
LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>x.var:repaymentAmounts) y;
```